# What is 'cat' used for?

Tags: command-line, cat

I've seen the cat command come up in some online stuff and I was curious as to what `cat` did and what it's for in the context of someone who is just doing some simple command line stuff.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`cat`'s primary purpose is to con*cat*enate files. `cat file1 file2 ...` will show the contents of `file`, `file2` and the others one after the other, as if the contents were in a single file. See the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cat.1posix):

```
NAME
       cat - concatenate and print files
```

It is meant for usage where either:

- a target command cannot read from files and you need to pass multiple files to it. An example is the [`tr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/tr.1) utility. Ordinarily, with one file, you'd do:

  ```
  tr < file
  ```

  But with multiple files, redirection can't be used, so you have to do:

  ```
  cat file1 file2 ... | tr
  ```
- a target command *can* read from multiple files, but its behaviour may change when it's given multiple files. An example is [`wc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/wc.1), which prints the counts for each file, along with the filenames, where you might have wanted just the total, without a filename.

Remember that most commands you encounter (`grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `sort`, ...) can read files perfectly fine.

If you want to *view* the contents of a file, **use a [pager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144016/what-is-a-pager)** - [`less`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/less.1) and [`more`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/more.1) are both eminently capable of presenting files for viewing, and are far more convenient to use.

Comment: Redirection can very well be used with multiple files as you can combine it with process and command substitution: `< <(cat file[12]) tr` as well as `<<<$(cat file[12]) tr` are both perfectly valid ways to redirect multiple files. Of course you need `cat` for that as well, just that piping is not the only way.

Comment: @dessert if you have to be pedantic, that redirection still uses only a single file - the file representing the command's stdout (or stdin, if the other way around). Bash doesn't support true multi-file redirection like zsh does.

Answer (score 12):

`cat` is one of the most frequently used commands on Unix-like operating systems. It has three related functions with regard to text files:

1. displaying them
2. combining copies of them
3. creating new ones.
4. Copy files

cat's general syntax is:

```
cat [options] [filenames] [-] [filenames]
```

#### Reading Files

The most common use of cat is to read the contents of files, and cat is often the most convenient program for this purpose. All that is necessary to open a text file for viewing on the display monitor is to type the word cat followed by a space and the name of the file and then press the ENTER key. For example, the following will display the contents of a file named file1:

```
cat file1
```

#### Concatenation

The second role of cat is concatenation. (This is the source of cat's curious name.)
There is no effect on the original files.

For example, the following command will concatenate copies of the contents of the three files file1, file2 and file3:

```
cat file1 file2 file3
```

The contents of each file will be displayed on the monitor screen. This output could just as easily be redirected using the output redirection operator to another file, such as file4, using the following:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > file4
```

#### File Creation

Thanks to [@muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) comment : **cat is capable of create new files depending on the shell redirection feature and not itself**

For small files this is often easier than using vi, gedit or other text editors. It is accomplished by typing cat followed by the output redirection operator and the name of the file to be created, then pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and finally simultaneously pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> & <kbd>d</kbd> keys.

For example, a new file named file1 can be created by typing

```
cat > file1
```

then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and simultaneously press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> & <kbd>d</kbd> keys.

*PS1: If a file named file1 already exists, it will be overwritten*

*PS2: you can append to exited file using append operator `>>` example cat >> file1*

#### Copy Files

The cat command can also be used (**depending** on shell redirection feature) to create a new file and transfer to it the data from an existing file. Example: make a copy of file `oldfile.txt`:

```
cat oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

References:

- [Linux and Unix cat command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucat.htm)
- [The cat Command](http://www.linfo.org/cat.html)
- [cat (Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix))
- [HowTo: Use cat Command In Linux / UNIX](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-cat-command-in-unix-linux-shell-script/)

Comment: Re 3: *`cat`* isn't creating those files - the shell is when you used redirection. You might have as well done `echo foo > file1`.

Comment: @muru You are totally right, but it still a use of cat command

Comment: No, it isn't. You are attributing to `cat` what is actually being done by something else.  For example, doing `less file1 > file2` (or `grep '.*' file1 > file` or `awk 1 file1 > file2` or ...) has the same effect. Ditto for 4. These are just misuses.

Comment: I know I could use it just `> file` and give same result, but can't I consider it valid to do that with cat?!

Comment: You can, *if* you specify that `cat` isn't creating the file. Saying `cat` creates or copies the file is just plain false.

Comment: I'' fix the syntax

Answer (score 1):

It can be used to show the contents of a file. Eg: `cat "my file.txt"`. You can also do `man cat` to show you the details about what `cat` can be used for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [another way](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) for file creation using shell redirection (or piping) and `cat`:

```sh
cat << EOF > foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Hello World!'
EOF
```

`cat << EOF` will output the following lines until the string `EOF` is encountered again. Then `>` (`>>`) will redirect the output to the file `foo.sh`. Alternatively, if you need to create a file as root, you can pipe the output to the command `tee` (`tee -a`), executed by the command `sudo`:

```sh
cat << EOF | sudo tee foo.sh && sudo chmod +x foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
HELLO='Hello World!'
echo "\$HELLO"
EOF
```

- The above will make the file executable (`chmod +x`) if it is successfully created (`&&`).
- The special meaning of some characters (as `$`) should be escaped (with `\`) within the output of `cat`.